# Website button to open GPS navigation app using smartphones

Tags: javascript, android, ios, gps

I would like to add the button to website for smartphones to open location (latitude, longitude) as the target in GPS navigation app. I read that clicking the link to e.g.:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?q=48.6724821,19.696058
```

with Android/iOS opens the Google Maps App. However, there may not be installed Google Maps app on the smartphone but some alternative - Sygic, Waze, Mapfactor etc. Is it possible or does exist Javascript library to open the address with an available GPS Navigation app or do another GPS apps recognize the above link?

Comment: Android has the "geo" scheme, e.g. "geo:48.6724821,19.696058" or "geo:0,0?q=ibiza+spain"; Windows Phone uses the "maps" scheme, e.g. "maps:?q=ibiza+spain". But in many cases, if a phone has a mapping app installed, it will know how to hijack a link to Google Maps.

Comment: Thanks @m69 so i could rely on Google Maps scheme - there is high possibility that other apps recognize it, too

Comment: I don't have any exact figures. You should probably check the apps you mentioned, and see whether they know how to hijack google maps links in different browsers on different platforms. If you find that it works for e.g. 90% of users, that may or may not be enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Google Maps URL Scheme:**

> A URL scheme allows you to launch a native iOS application from
>   another iOS app or a web application. You can set options in the URL
>   that will be passed to the launched application.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Example: `<a href="comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14">Manhattan</a>`

**iOS URL Scheme Reference**

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Example: `<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?sll=38.897517,-77.036542">The White House</a>`

The important thing is that your link should always contain proper parameters or it will be opened in Safari instead.

Comment: thanks @teamnorge. Do you have experience with other platforms? Is it sufficient to provide link to Google Maps? Do other GPS Navi apps recognize it?

Comment: I did just tested on FireOS the link in a format you provided: `https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en-US&gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=ssl&um=1&ie=UTF-8&fb=1&ll=42.3600825,-71.0588801&z=9&ftid=0x89e3652d0d3d311b:0x787cbf240162e8a0&q=Boston,+MA,+USA` it proposed opening it in Amazon Maps app. Other systems, I do not have an access to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Waze Deep Links.
Link looks like this - waze://?ll=48.6724821,19.696058&navigate=yes
It will open waze on your smartphone (if installed) and navigate to coordinates.
You can read more here:
https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks